# How to select most frequent value after group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to categorize a certain entity, let's say, a User, with the most frequent value associated in a table to this entity, let's say, an Emotion.

Thus,a User will be categorized as "Sad" when he logs mostly the value "Sad", or "Happy" when he logs mostly the value "Happy".

An example of the origin table:

| user_id | emotion | registered_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "PAM" | "SAD" | 2021-04-05 |
| "PAM" | "HAPPY" | 2021-04-06 |
| "PAM" | "HAPPY" | 2021-04-07 |
| "TIM" | "SAD" | 2021-04-06 |
| "TIM" | "SAD" | 2021-05-01 |
| "TIM" | "HAPPY" | 2021-06-05 |

the result I'm looking for:

| user_id | year | emotion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "TIM" | 2021 | "SAD" |
| "PAM" | 2021 | "HAPPY" |

I'm stuck with Mysql 5.7 so I cannot use window functions.

this is the select I came up with, was planning on using it as a subquery to choose from,
but now I'm stuck as to how to select only the rows with the higher value in how_many_times for each user.

```
select
    user_id,
    YEAR(MAX(registered_on)) as year,
    emotion,
    COUNT(user_id) as how_many_times
from users_emotions
group by user_id, emotion
order by user_id, how_many_times desc
```

can anyone help?

This is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQnSQZpAorT48Rv2DRMjxS/2

**Edit:**

So I was almost there, the answer marked as duplicate helped me, not the one marked as the right one, but the one by Vishal Kumar:

(eliminated year for clarity)

```sql
select ordered.user_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ordered.emotion order by ordered.how_many_times desc), ',',1) as emotions from 
(select
    user_id,
    COUNT(user_id) as how_many_times,
    emotion
from users_emotions
group by user_id, emotion) as ordered
group by ordered.user_id
;
```

I understand it's not perfect, because in case of a tie, it just picks one, but it does what I need!

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qyj341zapSob6pvAkcw7Fd/0

Comment: You say you're stuck on MySQL 5.7, but _why_ are you stuck on 5.7?

Comment: "...I'm stuck with Mysql 5.7..." -- MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life 7 months from now. Time to upgrade.

Comment: In your real case do you know the overall number of different emoticons at design time?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/2055998) and scroll to `MySQL 5.x`  section.

Comment: @Dai because I have no saying in what goes into the production server

Comment: @TheImpaler welcome to my life :-(

Answer (score 1):

The query would differ much from MySQL 5.x to MySQL 8, you onoly would use CTE's

With only two emotions this is quite easy

**Query #1**

```
SELECT

    user_id,year_emotion,
    CASE WHEN how_many_happy = how_many_unhappy THEN 'middle' 
    WHEN how_many_happy > how_many_unhappy THEN 'HAPPY'
    ELSE 'SAD' END emotions
FROM    
(select
    user_id,
    YEAR(registered_on) year_emotion,
    SUM( emotion =  "HAPPY") as how_many_happy,    
    SUM( emotion =  "SAD") as how_many_unhappy
from users_emotions
group by user_id, YEAR(registered_on)) t1
ORDER  BY user_id
;
```

| user_id | year_emotion | emotions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | SAD |
| 2 | 2021 | middle |
| 3 | 2021 | SAD |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQnSQZpAorT48Rv2DRMjxS/4)

with 3 it gets more complicated

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT

    user_id,year_emotion,
    CASE WHEN how_many_happy = how_many_unhappy 
          AND  how_many_happy = how_many_confused THEN 'middle' 
    WHEN how_many_happy >= how_many_unhappy THEN 
       CASE  WHEN how_many_happy > how_many_confused then   'HAPPY'
             ELSE 'COnfused' END 
    ELSE 
    CASE WHEN how_many_unhappy > how_many_confused then   'SAD'
    ELSE 'COMNFUSED'
     END 
     END emotions
FROM    
(select
    user_id,
    YEAR(registered_on) year_emotion,
    SUM( emotion =  "HAPPY") as how_many_happy,    
    SUM( emotion =  "SAD") as how_many_unhappy
 ,SUM( emotion =  "CONFUSED") as how_many_confused
from users_emotions
group by user_id, YEAR(registered_on)) t1
ORDER  BY user_id
;
```

| user_id | year_emotion | emotions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | SAD |
| 2 | 2021 | HAPPY |
| 3 | 2021 | COMNFUSED |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQnSQZpAorT48Rv2DRMjxS/6)

Comment: Completely different solution from mine, but i like it :)

Comment: thanks! but ideally, the user can write whatever they want, so I can't take for granted what they will write. Should have clarified that.

Comment: you can write a dynamic query, that first get all the emotions and make the query alone, but it is of course tricky

Comment: but sql is not a dataware house, it will ponly find data, that you know that exist, but usually for a study you will give a number of emotions to choose from, that makes that makes the query deterministic

Answer (score 0):

You could groupe the data by columns `user_id, Year, and emotion` and then selecting the row with the highest `count` for each `user_id, Year, and emotion` combination using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. The resulting output shows the `user_id, Year, and emotion` for each row with the highest count:

Query:

```sql
SELECT
  user_id,
  Year,
  emotion
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      DATE_FORMAT(registered_on, '%Y') AS Year,
      emotion,
      COUNT(*) AS count,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY
          COUNT(*) DESC
      ) rn
    FROM
      users_emotions
    GROUP BY
      user_id,
      Year,
      emotion
  ) t
WHERE
  rn = 1
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQnSQZpAorT48Rv2DRMjxS/5)

Comment: he has no MySQL 8

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's MysSql 5.7, then you can not use window functions and common table expressions. So, you have to use derived tables (subqueries) few times:

```
select t1.*
from (
 select 
    user_id, 
    emotion,
    YEAR(registered_on) as regyear,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
 from users_emotions
 group by 1, 2, 3
) as t1
where t1.cnt =  (
  select 
  MAX(cnt) as mcnt
  from (
    select 
      user_id, 
      emotion,
      YEAR(registered_on) as regyear,
      COUNT(*) as cnt
    from users_emotions
    group by 1, 2, 3) as sq
);
```

[Updated Sql fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQnSQZpAorT48Rv2DRMjxS/7)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a small number of pre-defined `emotions` (categories), then nbk's method will perform much better than this.

This will work for any number of possible `emotions` but uses a slightly arbitrary `e1.emotion > e2.emotion` to break any ties:

```sql
SELECT e1.user_id, e1.reg_year AS year, e1.emotion
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id, 
        emotion,
        YEAR(registered_on) as reg_year,
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM users_emotions
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
) e1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        user_id, 
        emotion,
        YEAR(registered_on) as reg_year,
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM users_emotions
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
) e2
    ON e1.user_id = e2.user_id
    AND e1.reg_year = e2.reg_year
    AND (e1.cnt < e2.cnt OR
         e1.cnt = e2.cnt AND e1.emotion > e2.emotion)
WHERE e2.user_id IS NULL
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V4NUHci7)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following aggregation with a correlated subquery in the having clause:

```
select user_id, 
       emotion, 
       year(max(registered_on)) year_
from users_emotions ue
group by user_id, emotion
having count(*) = 
  (
    select max(cnt)
    from
    (
      select user_id, emotion, count(*) cnt
      from users_emotions
      group by user_id, emotion
    ) mx
    where mx.user_id = ue.user_id
  )
order by user_id
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bXvcjbXj)